# How to detect image changes on web page using python?

Tags: python, monitoring

Regarding to website monitoring or changes detection, i would know how can i **detect if an image on a web page has been replaced** by another ?

**Note**: i know that if it was uploaded to an external server, i can do some url checks, but in my case, if it was replaced with the same name locally, then the url is the same, picture no.

I would use python3 for this tool.

Comment: you could use some image library like `PIL` or `OpenCV` or even `numpy`, a quick way to do it is to download the image and check the histogram of pixels, i.e, the number of pixels of each color, if this number changes then image changed. Keep in mind that you will need to do it always from the same device as sometimes webpages have different sizes for different devices

Comment: Download the file, compute a hash of it, and save the hash.  Then periodically download the file again and compute the hash.  If the new hash does not equal the original hash, then the file has changed.

Comment: Or you can do a HEAD request on that image and look at the Last-Modified response header.